# How can I pass a path name with underscore in a yaml-file to latex via pandoc?

Tags: pandoc, csvsimple

I have a `csv`-file called `test_csv.csv` which has this content:

```
1_c,2,3,4
a2,b,c,d
```

I would like to print it with LaTeX and `csvautobooklongtable` but wihin a pandoc-workflow.

The pandoc-template (`pandoc-csv.latex`) is this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\csvautobooklongtable[before table=\ttfamily,respect all]{$pathtocsv$}
\end{document}
```

The path to the `csv`-file is in an extra `yaml`-file (`my.yaml`):

```
---
pathtocsv: test_csv.csv
---
```

Since I only have metadata I would like to print there is an empty markdown dummy-file which seems to be necessary (`dummy.md`) for pandoc.

I do the conversion via CLI and

```
pandoc my.yaml --template pandoc-csv.latex  dummy.md --pdf-engine=lualatex -o pandoc-csv.pdf
```

---

The problem is that pandoc converts the underscore from the path name and it cannot be read in my latex document.

> ! Package csvsimple Error: File 'test\_csv.csv' not existent, not readable
> , or empty!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to to tell pandoc, that the string is already `latex` to avoid further escaping:

```
---
pathtocsv: "`test_csv.csv`{=latex}"
---
```